# Java Spring обработка больших объемов данных

Tags: java, spring

Опишу задачу, прошу подсказки куда смотреть. Надо обработать большое количество данных как можно быстрее и эффективнее.
Задача скорее всего типичная:
1. Спарсить 3-4 сайта (желательно одновременно)
2. Обработать эти данные в нужный формат для вставки в базу
3. Закинуть все это добро в базу

С технологиями баз и парсинга определился, но теперь не могу определиться как все это сделать быстро и производительно. Как бы в спринге есть @Async и можно сделать параллельный парсинг. Смотрел также в сторону Spring Batch, но не могу понять в нем есть многопоточность "под капотом" или он просто тупо дробит большое задание на части? В общем подскажите пожалуйста какую технологию применить, как вы бы решили данную задачу?

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Сколько данных, насколько быстро нужно? Если сайта 3-4, то почему бы не написать просто один метод, который парсит сайт, а дальше не воспользоваться ThreadPoolExecutor с отдельным Runable на каждый сайт? Плюс я бы на вашем месте посмотрел на оптимизацию в другую сторону. А именно разбивания процесса парсинга в стрим, возможно с использованием чего то вроде RxJava, чтобы можно парить и сохранять в бд одновременно. Это если тормоза будут на стороне сервера. Если на стороне БД - очень часто есть Batch вставки в БД.